# how to stop automatic open of LibOffice with an empty document?

Tags: 15.04

When Ubuntu 15.04 starts, it open an empty document with Lib... how to stop this ?

I tried to find if there is a start-up directory / program, have not find any.

Comment: Look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html) and see if that helps. it is about starting an app at startup but if it is in that application then you can disable it there as well

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the Dash:

[image]

2. Type Startup Applications
3. Pick the application you want to remove at Ubuntu startup

This should resolve your problem.